Domain coloring
Checking the latest release of domaincoloring package (and previous versions too) we see that the function f(z)=z, that is the default plane coloring, gives a coloring that has many repetitions. Many half lines, starting at zero have the same colors on them. With this default coloring how one is to understand what, for example, f(z)=z^2 does on the plane?
I would expect that the default coloring is a simple one so that each half line has different colors, like the top of the cylinder in  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:HSV_color_solid_cylinder_alpha_lowgamma.png
In any case the question is how to get a simple default coloring like the above (of wikipedia).
If we start from a color circle that argument changes hue like this:

and distance from zero changes lightness like this:

then the following graph:

shows a function that has three roots (at 1, 2 and 3) where the number (1) shows a double root, (2) and (3) simple roots, and two poles at (4) and (5). This is because the original painting has black at zero and white at infinity. I would prefer the opposite (black for poles and infinity and roots painted zero) but these pictures clarify I think what is needed as a minimum; to be able to see roots and poles.

I suppose that you mean a setting like hsvrgb={phi+pi,1,1}, but this is not the default of the package. It is hsvrgb={phi+pi,1,r}. If I modify this setting to
domain={-2,2,-2,2},hsvrgb={0.5,r/2,2-r}]{1/(z^3-1)}

I'll get

I am not a mathematician, so I cannot say if it is wrong or not.

Trying to clarify, the question is to set the default. that is to set how the function f(z)=z is graphed. Not the z^2. The default must use a full say value (255), hue for phi ranging from 0 to 359 (or 1 to 360) and r (distance from zero) ranging from 0 to 255 scaled to fit the radius of the canvas.

Update TL and compare the new version of domaincoloring

OK, just checked. Although it is much better it still needs improvements to be useful for math. it seems to me that each point on each half line starting at zero is painted with the same color. that is, all half lines are uniformly colored. This does not help to visualize. It is needed to blacken (or whiten) as you go out. Currently it seems that you change colors based on Arg and r is ignored. Check for example the negative real axis. It is white at every point. It shouldn't be. As it stands we can not visualize zeros and we can not visualize poles.

Personally I would prefer zero to be painted white and infinity to be painted black. So when a function (other than z) is graphed white spots show roots and black spots show poles. In any case the current default coloring is uniform per half line, that is it ignores r, so I guess this should be considered a bug.

Also useful would be a way to set the default at least setting z as default or 1/z as default. This would allow to reversely label roots by black and poles by white. Although I personally prefer the roots white and poles black as described above.

See ma edited answer.

If the target is ti get a "beautiful" picture this is fine. But if one is to understand something from it, I am not sure it is correct. This function has three poles of rank 1. How do I understand this from this picture? What is the rule? Assume I do not know which is the function that this picture graphs. How do I identify that the graph shows 3 poles of rank one? Maybe I have to show you an example. I will do that.

see please the edited question.
